# How would I count all unique values of a dataframe in python without double counting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose I have a python data frame that looks something like this:

```
Factor_1    Factor_2    Factor_3   Factor_4   Factor_5
   A           B           A          Nan       Nan
   B           D           F          A         Nan
   F           A           D          B          A
```

Something like this in which I have 5 columns that have different factors. I would like to create a column that counts how many of this factors appear in the dtaframe but without double counting in what terms without double counting if the value apperas in one row it only counts it as 1 for example if one row has A, B, C, A, A only 1 A would be counted. The expected out output would be this.

```
Factor   Count
  A        3
  B        3
  D        2
  F        2
 Nan       2
```

I used a a code I was helped with

```
df.stack(dropna=False).value_counts(dropna=False)
```

I was using an if to drop the double count but I would like to know if there is a practical and simple way to do this, like  the code above, and not with an If because what I am doing is not efficient.

Comment: How can `A` have four counts following your logic, if there are 3 rows?

Comment: My bad I shoould be 3 sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.unique` + `Series.value_counts`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.hstack(df.T.apply(pd.Series.unique))).value_counts(dropna=False)
```

---

```
B      3
A      3
F      2
D      2
NaN    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I understand the logic of what you are doing but when I apply to my code It gives back the error ValueError: arrays must all be same length I actually don't know why it gives back that error

Comment: For me its working fine..@anky any ideas? Is the code working fine on the sample data you have provided?

Comment: No I just checked and it isn't its actullay giving me the same error

Comment: The error was due to an older version of pandas, if it can help someone update pandas and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way following your logic , additionally chaining a conditional check using `groupby` on `level=0`

```
s = df.stack(dropna=False)
s.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x[~x.duplicated()]).value_counts(dropna=False)
```

---

```
A      3
B      3
D      2
F      2
NaN    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes my bad sorry just changed it